# url rewrite to cut folder names

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have some folders where are structures like this

***test*** >***main*** >***pages***>***general***(inside pages I have my index.php, contact.php etc)

at the moment my url looks something like this

```
www.test.com/test/main/pages/general.index.php
```

how can i rewrite this so i can cut all the folders out and just show

```
www.test.com/index.php
```

**I have done**

```
RewriteEngine on

AuthUserFile "/home/amytesting/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
AuthName "root"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/test\.com/\ " [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove folder name from url using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com$
RewriteRule ^contact$ http://contactx.test.com/contactX/contact-question.cfm
```

Comment: if I put index.php does that mean i need to put all the other files or isnt they a best way to just say if folder in general it should cut out the all the other folders?

Comment: i dont want to show `www.test.com/test/main/pages/general.index.php` i want to show `www.test.com/index.php`

Comment: basically anything in the general folder should be cut out to `www.test.com/THE FILE NAME

Comment: if u sent the website... `www.test.com` i want it to show the index.php page. when u click on any of the nav link like contact page it whould be `www.test.com/conatct.php` or www.test.com/contact`

Comment: i just found out why my code wasn't working it because godaddy windows plan doesn't support .htaccess

Comment: But you can't move your page ?

Comment: It was my first time buying a url and web hosting with godaddy... I choose windows plan but i didnt know it only support ASP languages only all my file are `.php` which means i should have choose `linux`. I cant windows windows because all my files are save as `.php`.

Comment: Yes it's not a problem. You can move your files to the root folder and rename them.

Comment: `rename` my file to `aspx`? do u have any experience using godaddy?

Comment: No. I don't. But you are using php file and it seems that there are no problems.