# how to remove folder name from url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to change the URL from:

```
http://example.com/Portfolios/iPhone/app
```

To:

```
http://example.com/iPhone/app
```

And same for all URLs like:

```
example.com/Portfolios/iPad/app
```

To:

```
example.com/iPad/app
```

And from:

```
example.com/Portfolios/xyz/app
```

To:

```
example.com/xyz/app
```

I have tried a lot but nothing is working for me.

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^Portfolios(/.*|)$ $1 [L,NC]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It might help to know that redirects can be cached by the browser, I only just learned it after some hours; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499541/htaccess-file-somehow-being-cached

Comment: See this `Remove folder name from URLs` https://helponnet.com/2021/11/30/remove-folder-name-from-url/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through Apache config and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under **`DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Portfolios/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

**Explanation:** Above rule is matching URL pattern that starts with `Portfolios` and have somthing like `/Portfolios/xyz/app` and puts `xyz/app` in `$1`. It makes an external redirection to `/$1` i.e. `/xyz/app`.

These are the flags used:

```
L  - Last Rule
NC - Ignore (No) Case comparison
R  - External redirection (with 302)
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: when I tried RewriteRule ^Portfolios(/.*|)$ $1 [L,NC] there are no effects, when I tried RewriteRule ^Portfolios(/.*|)$ $1 [L,NC,R=301] Its redirecting with folder structure C:/wamp/www/project...

Comment: I have tried url: http://domain.com/Portfolios/iPad/app and htaccess placed in root

Comment: @anytime: I believe `Portfolios` is a folder directly below DOCUMENT_ROOT is that correct?

Comment: @anubhava yes buddy, n thanks for your help :) , I want to enable both the url like:http://domain.com/Portfolios & http://domain.com/iPhone/app (redirect from http://domain.com/Portfolios/iPhone/app)

Comment: @anytime: Can you try this rule: `RewriteRule ^Portfolios/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]` and let me know.

Comment: anubhava, [**I insert your code in my `.htaccess`**](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/.htaccess#L16-L21) → I create [**Kristinita.github.io/Portfolios/bar/app.html**](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/Portfolios/bar/app.html) file. If `http://kristinita.github.io/Portfolios/bar/app.html`, `app.html` was opened for me; but if `http://kristinita.github.io/bar/app.html`, I get 404 error. What I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: As you can see your 2nd URL doesn't even have `Portfolios/` at the start so this rule won't redirect.

Comment: @anubhava, all right. Now [**http://kristinita.github.io/Portfolios/app.html**](http://kristinita.github.io/bar/app.html) successfully open for me, but [**http://kristinita.github.io/bar/app.html**](http://kristinita.github.io/bar/app.html) — 404 error. But the author of the question asked on the contrary — that [**http://kristinita.github.io/bar/app.html**](http://kristinita.github.io/bar/app.html) file was open. How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных: OP just asked for removal of `/Portfolios/` from every URL. You seem to be having a different problem. Open a new question with all the details and I will try to answer.

Comment: What does this do `RewriteBase /`

Comment: @anubhava I am using your example as `RewriteBase /coronavirus/dashboard/` `RewriteRule ^region/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]` to remove `/region` from https://quarantine.country/coronavirus/dashboard/region/usa/ but can't get it to work. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: @Yatko: Can you please post a separate question with all details and I will try to post a solution.

Comment: @anubhava thank you! Please see the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916016/htaccess-url-rewrite-remove-folder-from-url

Comment: oh nvm I guess the question was different than I expected, removed my comment

Comment: can't change it

Comment: ok, done, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your root directory as /var/www/Portfolios instead of /var/www/ in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled by writing DocumentRoot line as

> DocumentRoot /var/www/Portfolios

instead of 
DocumentRoot /var/www/
and also this line
< Directory /var/www/ > changed to

> < Directory /var/www/Portfolios/ >

Comment: I get `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this resource.` after doing this!