# Change site root directory with php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change the root of my website with php functions.

This is my website (mysite.com)

This website using (current root document) and loading from `index.php` like this

```
mysite.com /
  index.php
  folder1
  folder2
```

now I want when we open (mysite.com) show index.php inside of folder1.(change the root to /folder1/ )

I can use redirect but my address will be like this `mysite.com/folder1`

but I want this website (`mysite.com`) using `/folder1/` as root directory with out we want to user (`mysite.com/folder1`)

What should I do? What is the functions for this to use in  `index.php` (to use folder1 as root directory)?

Comment: You will need to either edit your `apache` server and point to root to `/folder1`. If you do not have access to this, you will have to edit your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: You don't change your webserver config from PHP. Indeed you should go to great lengths to *prevent* PHP from modifying the webserver config (including .htaccess files). Otherwise you have no security.

Answer (score 4):

This is an excellent fit for .htaccess usage if you can't access the httpd.conf.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Change yourdomain.com to be your primary domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourprimarydomain.com$

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/

# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1

# Change yourdomain.com to be your primary domain again. 
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourmaindomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I'll add my voice to the other comments on this question - You should change your root through your Apache conf files if possible. This is a good option if you are not able to. I'd even just move everything from /folder2 into the root instead. Simplify the process as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your .htaccess to change the file it default loads:

```
# Set the startfile to something else:
DirectoryIndex folder1/index.php
```

**Changing basic functionality is a stupid thing to do***. It's confusing, especially for people who are new to the code, or if you look back in a year or so. It will slow down progress and development in the long run. **A big no go!***

**Unless you know what you are doing. Which you're not if you have to ask :)*

---

If you are very sure you want to go through with this, you can set the DOCUMENT_ROOT to something else.

```
// Place this as high as possible in your code, like a config
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].= '/folder1';
```

To provide a more professional method, you could [change the document_root in the httpd.conf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html), and have the php $_server value set to the new value **serverwide**.

Comment: i want php functions not htaccess ... php function to use in index.php to change root to /folder1/files...

Comment: @user3464859 The alternative would be to use an `include` of the index within that directory. Otherwise, you can look into routing.

Answer (score 0):

Some other Q&As from SO that might help:

[How do I change the root directory of an apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)

[how to remove folder name from url using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want use php, you can place index.php file in you root dir with this content:

```
<?php
  header('Location: /folder1/');
?>
```

Althought, better way to do this, is with htaccess.

Comment: this will direct to /folder1 !!! i dont want to use direct !!! i want to change root not direct it