# Remove folder form URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I had moved my website to one step back. So before that the link was `www.example.com/abc/test.php`, but now the link is `www.example.com/test.php`.

I want to remove the `abc` folder name from the links, if any user visit the links containing the `abc` folder I want to remove `abc` folder from it.

I have tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This link will helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```