# Remove folder to URL with querystrings

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL, that in the past. It was accessed as in the example below `http://example.com.br/blog` but today its as `example.com.br`.

However, I have external access to queries strings pointing to the folder:

`example.com.br/blog/?utm_source=mkt&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign...etc`

I want all requests to remove the folder:

`example.com.br/?utm_source=mkt&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign...etc`

What rules should I create in the .htaccess file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18973073/1183790

Comment: Can you clarify your expected behavior and include more detail in your example?  How are the query parameters relevant to your problem?

Comment: The behavior I want is everything you get in this URL:

example.com.br/blog/?utm_source=mkt&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign...etc

Be redirected to is

example.com.br/?utm_source=mkt&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign...etc

All requests that have / blog, the / blog to be removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ / [L,NC,R=301]
```

The query string does not change