# Using htaccess remove folder name

Tags: php, .htaccess

my project is in core PHP with some folder structure which contain views folder but I do not want to show it so I have tried a lot in htaccess but not get success

I want url structure

```
http://example.com/views/interest-areas.php?id=MTY=
```

to

```
http://example.com/interest-areas.php?id=MTY=
```

I have taken reference of [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess) but still now getting expected result

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `/views/` fodler?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^users/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ views/$1 [L]
```

Here, the [L]-flag stops rewriting after this rule, preventing possible circle-reactions etc

Comment: The second line has unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in root directory,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /views/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ views/$1.php [QSA,L]
```