# How to rewrite url in apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say I've got a site `example.com/books/linux`

I want to rewrite the url to `books.example.com/linux` without doing anything else (without redirecting/moving files to a different location on a server etc.).

So how can I just rewrite the url using apache2?

I would be glad to read your answers. Thank you very much!

Comment: When you enter "example.com/linux" as a url, you could setup a redirect page which would take you to the actual location. I.e: "example.com/books/linux".

Comment: OR, check this thread out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess

Comment: It should be just like alias. So when I open example.com/books/linux it goes to book.example.com/linux (different domain name) and the other way around. It should serve the same files from the same location on the filesystem. As I understand redirect will throw me to a different location.

Comment: In that case, I believe you should refer to the first answer on the thread I linked