# How to Redirect URL using .access from domain.org/xxx/archive/ to domain.org/archive /wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain.org website which uses Wordress and it was located in `domain.org/owp/`, I moved the content to `domain.org/` and everything works fine but there are old posts with urls that has `/owp/` with them *they are on fb* so how can I redirect those to the correct new URL?

This is the site `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

thank you

Comment: You could use a wildcard: domain.org/owp/* domain.org/* meaning any url with owp directory path should go to the url without that directory path instead, and keep everything else.

Comment: can you show me how to do it?

Comment: I use Simple 301 Redirects for this, enter the urls, then select "Wild card" checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't answer this as a comment.

I think it has already been solved here: [how to remove folder name from url using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess)

Hopefully it will be helpful.