# How to remove a part of a url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am building a `modular` website and I want to set up a folder for people to put their own plugins with the structure being:

```
htdocs
└plugins
 └notes
   ├ createnote.php
   ├ deletenote.php
   ├ editnote.php
   └ viewnote.php
```

I would like to remove the `plugins` from the URL. 
So instead of the URL being `https://example.com/plugins/notes/createnote.php` I would like it to read as `https://example.com/notes/createnote.php`.

I tried using [introduction to url rewriting](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)  to help me but I didn't completely understand it.

EDIT:
I found a solution [Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/72353)!

Comment: This post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess

Comment: That didn't end up working for me, but thanks anyways :)