# Change visible URL to another

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want to change the URL from one to another. Exactly from this:

https://example.com/pages/page.php

to this:

https://example.com/page.php

Physically page.php is in the /pages folder and I want to left it like that. I want to change the visible URL only.

I've tried to use rewrite with htaccess like this: 
`RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC]` but it returns 404.

## Update

I've tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

and now I see page.php from both https://example.com/pages/page.php and https://example.com/page.php without 404.

BUT it's still not exactly what I expected. I want after going here https://example.com/pages/page.php to see: https://example.com/page.php

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove folder name from url using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess)

Comment: Yes, I saw it and tried. This is the same, I have 404 ;) Autor of this post have the same problem, you can see in comments.

Comment: You can access both URLs? If so what happens if you redirect URL by adding this line at bottom of htaccess: `Redirect /pages/page.php /page.php`

Answer (score -3):

ModRewrite would be a more decent solution I think, but in PHP you could just use include/require

```
# /page.php
require_once('./pages/page.php');
```

Comment: The OP says: **Physically page.php is in the /pages folder and I want to left it like that**

Comment: True, my answer is not valid here, but if OP didn't want an PHP valid solution, there shouldn't be a PHP tag.

Comment: OP uses PHP tag cause he is using Apache with PHP. He want redirect/rewrite or some other function for PHP. `.htaccess` I use for PHP only not sure about you.

Comment: "or some other function for PHP" - And I gave him an answer for PHP, which OP doesn't want. That is ok. Still, Apache and rewrite has little to nothing to with php per se.