# .htaccess URL rewrite (remove folder from URL)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

Trying to show `quarantine.country/coronavirus/dashboard/usa/` instead of `quarantine.country/coronavirus/dashboard/region/usa/` at our [covid-19 dashboard](https://quarantine.country/coronavirus/dashboard/region/usa/) for US, using [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess):

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /coronavirus/dashboard/

RewriteRule ^region/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

- please let me know why the solution above doesn's seem to have the desired rewrite. Thank you!

Comment: I have my URL like `https://www.test.com/something/en/home`. Here my code is in directory `something` but from URL i need to remove it. So URL should be `https://www.test.com/en/home`. I tried above rule with `RewriteBase /` but it's not working @yatko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use these rules in `/coronavirus/dashboard/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /coronavirus/dashboard/

RewriteRule ^(?!region/).*$ region/$0 [L,NC]
```

This will let you use URL as:
 `https://quarantine.country/coronavirus/dashboard/usa/`

Comment: I have my URL `https://www.test.com/something/en/home`. Here my code is in directory `something` but from URL i need to remove it. So URL should be `https://www.test.com/en/home`. I tried above rule with `RewriteBase /` but it's not working @anubhava

Comment: Please open a new question then I can probably understand it better to help you out