# Domain redirection to apache subfolder and removal of extensions from url

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, web

I have two questions im struggling with :

1. I have a static web pages in the following directory of my apache :

`var/www/folder/`

I have managed to redirect my domain to the above folder to load the html pages, however the when I go to the domain the url shows `domain.com/folder` Now I understand I need to change the sites-available in the etc/apache2 folder in order to directly hit the domain.com however im trying to achieve it without having to change the etc/apache2 sites-available. Is there a way?

The reason I do not want to change the sites-available is because there is a folder2 inside www which I need to access at some point. How do I redirect the domain without showing the folder on  the url?

2. Inside the www/folder/ I have a few php pages, Now I have tried using .htaccess in the www and inside www/folder/ to remove the .php from the url, however it doesn't seem to work. How do I remove the .php extension from the url?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the folder name from the URL then you should check this link. It has almost same issue, that you are facing.

[how to remove folder name from url using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess)

Beside this to remove .php Extension use this :

Option 1 :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Option 2:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: The above rewrite engine code to be written in .htaccess file in the root folder right?

Comment: the .php extension is removed successfully, however it shows page not found

Comment: try second option.. i have added above

Comment: No luck with the second option too

Comment: your domain name ?

Comment: Its an IP address, haven't put a domain to it yet. http://3.6.187.133/