# I want to remove folder and .php from URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect

1. `https://example.com/index.php` to `https://example.com`
2. `https://example.com/view/india.php` to `https://example.com/india`
3. `https://example.com/view/city/india/chennai.php` to `https://example.com/india/chennai`

This is what I want to achieve anyone please send me the `.htaccess` code for this problem.

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess
It describes how to remove a folder name from an url using .htaccess

Comment: I am new to .htaccess I tried to understand but can't I need the .htaccess code the questions I have asked.

Comment: Does your site know how to handle URLs of the form `/india` and `/india/chennai`? (Otherwise you need to do more than simply "redirect" the request.) What URLs are you currently linking to in your application? What do you currently have in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: I am new to .htaccess I tried to understand but can't I need the .htaccess code the questions I have asked.

Comment: This is the all the code, you won't need to do something else

Comment: The code doesn't work

Comment: This will result in a rewrite-loop (500 error) since it repeatedly appends `.php` to everything!